# Angularjs: Modifying inner html content provided by angular expression using angular directive

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a simple angular directive that adds the string 'yes' to the inner html content of an element if the corresponding scope option variable is greater than 1. When the inner html is an angular expression, the original text is preserved but 'yes' is not added to it regardless of the scope option variable value. I've fixed this by wrapping the code in my directive that modifies the inner html text inside a timeout function, but is there is a proper way of doing this without using the timeout?

example of code: http://plnkr.co/edit/OhePRiHNJvNfKgNcrbnQ?p=preview

Comment: You need to include some of the code as a part of your question

Answer (score 0):

$timeout is fine here. What's it actually doing is forcing the HTML to finish rendering first before the Javascript in the directive calls .html(). Without the timeout, the HTML rendering may not yet have finished in the browser.

Using timeout here isn't a hack - you could set the time to 0 and it'll still work. Just having the $timeout/setTimeout there moves the code in it to the end of the browser event queue - after the HTML rendering work finishes, which is what you want. [Why is setTimeout(fn, 0) sometimes useful?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/779379/why-is-settimeoutfn-0-sometimes-useful) has more details about how and why it works.